# ExpressionEngine Subscriptions Add-on: Unable to Integrate PayPal for User Subscriptions

Tags: expressionengine, expressionengine3

I'm currently facing an issue with integrating PayPal as a subscription option for users within the ExpressionEngine Subscriptions add-on (EE Harbor). I've been working on setting up a subscription feature on my website, allowing users to subscribe and pay for premium content using PayPal. However, I've encountered some challenges, and I'm seeking assistance to resolve them.

I have installed the ExpressionEngine Subscriptions add-on and followed the documentation to set up subscription plans. However, I'm unable to successfully integrate PayPal as a payment gateway for users to subscribe to these plans.

When I attempt to click on the "Subscribe Now" button after selecting a subscription plan, I encounter the following error: *"Fatal error: Call to a member function supportsCreateCard() on boolean in public_html/systemxtr/user/addons/subs/Service/Cards.php on line 21."*

I have tried various code implementations and configurations, but I'm unable to pinpoint the root cause of the issue. I need guidance on the correct code structure and configuration to enable seamless PayPal integration.